# Exportación a excel js en con columnas en vertical y horizontal

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

Estoy utilizando la librería xlsx.full.min.js para realizar exportaciones a Excel.

Funciona correctamente y puedo exportar mis documentos a excel desde un js. Ahora bien, mi duda es la siguiente, ¿Cómo podría realizar un excel con columnas en vertical y horizontal?, os pongo un ejemplo en la siguiente captura de pantalla de lo que quiero llegar a realizar.

En concreto , la parte que me gustaría saber como hacer es donde pone Nombre de llave, ¿Cómo puedo escribo las palabras en vertical?

¿Es esto posible con esta librería?, si no lo es, conocéis alguna alternativa para hacer esto con js.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchísimas gracias!!

Comment: *Columnas en vertical y horizontal* es un poco desconcertante. En Excel los datos en vertical se llaman columnas y en horizontal se llaman filas. Ahora bien, viendo la imagen, lo que tu deseas es orientar el texto de una celda en forma vertical. Eso es muy diferente a *columna vertical*. Lo que debes hacer es leer la documentación de la librería que usas y verificar si puedes o no configurar la orientación del texto de una celda de forma vertical. Saludos

Comment: Gracias, me ha servido tu respuesta